# Unable to connect to parse mongo db

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, port

I am using test server on parse server with mongodb. After rebooting, it is failed to connect with possible port connection issues. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is failing to connect? What is the command that you are running? What is the error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.